# To fetch data from mysql table using hooks codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, hook

I am new for hooks in codeigniter. I have enabled the hooks in config file.

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

and then in hooks.php I have written my hook that is like below

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
'class' => 'MyClass',
'function' => 'Myfunction',
'filename' => 'Myclass.php',
'filepath' => 'hooks',
'params' => '');
```

AND the class having function is as below

```
class MyClass {

function MyClass() {
    $this->CI = &get_instance();
    require_once(APPPATH . 'config/database.php');
}
function Myfunction() {
    $record = $this->CI->db->SELECT('*')
            ->FROM('currency')
            ->get()
            ->result();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($record);
    die;
}}
```

but i am getting a blank page. please tell me what is wrong with me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP? – Nothing is seen. The page is empty and white.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851)

Comment: yes, I want to fetch the data from that table. What should i have to do.@CBroe

Comment: First of all, you need to find out what the reason for the “blank page” is.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem was in this area.

```
function MyClass() {
    $this->CI = &get_instance();
    require_once(APPPATH . 'config/database.php');
}
```

Try

Note: codeigniter 3 versions are case sensitive should be first letter upper case only on **class** and **file name**.

application > hooks > My_class.php

```
<?php

class My_class {

public function __construct() {
    $this->CI = &get_instance();
    // Auto load database
    // require_once(APPPATH . 'config/database.php');
}


public function my_function() {
    $query = $this->CI->db->get('currency');

    $record = $query->result_array();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($record);
    echo "</pre>";

}

}
```

Config Hook

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
'class' => 'My_class',
'function' => 'my_function',
'filename' => 'My_class.php',
'filepath' => 'hooks',
);
```

Autoload the database better option

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Codeigniter [Hooks](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html#defining-a-hook)